# How to skip unnecessary XHR requests on redirecting some page while page load

Tags: cypress

How to skip unnecessary XHR requests on redirecting some page while page load

Comment: In my experience It loads because pages load asynchronously from api and need real time - in result it is actually a correct behavior. How do this hinder your work? If you stop the load of page your test will not be testing the actual page.

Comment: @RosenMihaylov: Hi thank you for the response but actually when i land on dashboard page the application keeps on sending the xhrs requests continously but the application is ready to use so i just want if there is an way we can control the xhr calling i used intercept stub but once page starts loading everything else got stopped

Comment: I had met this issue also, but since it is from the app, I just learn to live with such tasks unless it is my own and I can adapt it.